# how to get test fail message in NUnit TearDown

Tags: c#, nunit

Hi i would like to log the test failed message , I know its possible to check the status in

```
TearDown
```

Using the following

```
TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status.ToString();
```

Is possible to get the reason for test fail in TearDown . Some thing like the following

```
Expected: True
But was:  False

at NUnit.Framework.Assert.That(Object actual, IResolveConstraint expression, String message, Object[] args)
       at NUnit.Framework.Assert.IsTrue(Boolean condition)
       at Test.FileSystemTests.QuoteFiles() in ExampleTests.cs: line 57
```

Answer (score 5):

If

```
TestContext.CurrentContext.Result
```

does not contain the values you are looking for, you can also try

```
TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentResult
```

This worked for me with NUnit 3.0 in the TearDown as well as other methods.

Answer (score 1):

Hi am not sure you got the solution for this issue. But here is my answer for this. 
Using Nunit 3.0 you can achieve this with below lines...

```
TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status; (For test Execution Status)

TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.StackTrace; (For Stack Trace Message)

TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Message; (For Test Result Message)
```

Answer (score 0):

The need for a status in your teardown is an indication of a testsmell. The teardown should work any time without depending on the result of the unit test. I just brings your system in the same state as before your unit test. You can add tries and finally to your teardown to clean the mess. However depending on one assert (and later on more) will make your teardown code complex and that is something your do now want in an unit test.

Comment: The thing is i use Teardown to Write to a excel File , I am doing this since i am using selenium automation to test a webapp , i just want to know which assert failed or something else failed in the test , since it will be better to see the reason for the test fail in the excel rather than seeing just Test failed message in the excel . Try catch is not very good option for me .Thank u

Answer (score 0):

This question: [NUnit: Accessing the Failure Message in TearDown()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340934/nunit-accessing-the-failure-message-in-teardown) could potentially help you. It seems similar enough in intent.